# How do I map true/false/unknown to -1/0/null without repetition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am currently working on a tool to help my users port their SQL code to SQL-Server 2005. For this purpose, I parse the SQL into a syntax tree, analyze it for constructs which need attentions, modify it and transform it back into T-SQL.

On thing that I want to support, is the "bools are values too" semantics of other RDBMS. For example, MS-Access allows me to write `select A.x and A.y as r from A`, which is impossible in T-SQL because:

1. Columns can't have boolean type (column values can't be and'ed)
2. Logical predicates can not be used where expressions are expected.

Therefore, my transformation routine converts the above statement into this:

```
select case 
  when (A.x<>0) and (A.y<>0)
   then -1 
  when not((A.x<>0) and (A.y<>0)) 
   then 0 
  else 
   null 
  end as r 
 from A;
```

Which works, but is annoying, because I have to duplicate the logical expression (which can be very complex or contain subqueries etc.) in order to distinguish between `true`, `false` and `unknown` - the latter shall map to null. So I wonder if the T-SQL pro's here know a better way to achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
I would like to point out, that solutions which try to keep the operands in the integer domain have to take into account, that **some** operands may be logical expressions in the **first place**. This means that a efficient solution to convert a bool to a value is stil required. For example:

```
select A.x and exists (select * from B where B.y=A.y) from A;
```

Comment: Sorry, but how is it possible? I mean, when you have simple boolean operands (like boolean columns) you can/should compare them to integers, i.e. you *convert them to conditions*. But logical expresions, like `exists(...)`, are already conditions by themselves and should be taken 'as is'. How one can combine that in one query/one `CASE`/one whatever? Not in a static one, it seems. What I mean is, you may probably end up with a bigger fuss then simply duplicating expressions.

Comment: What is never mentioned is what you are doing with a Select statement like the one presented. I.e., something executes a query which returns a Boolean expression (in Access). How are the results of that query consumed?

Comment: @Luther I know I have answered before, but I have now reinterpreted and rewrote it. Let me know if the revision is more in line with what you are after

Comment: @Thomas: I am writing my library for the team ("my users") which uses this feature from Access in their applications. Don't ask me why they do this. It's probably because they are C/C++ programmers and find this convention quite natural.

Comment: @cyberwiki: Thanks for your update. I will evaluate the answers when I'm back to by desk on Monday.

Comment: There's another aspect complicating this issue. Access will use Bitwise operators when possible. If `1 And 2` is evaluated bitwise, the result will be 0 (False), but if evaluated Boolean-wise, it will be True. Don't you need to handle this difference as well?

Comment: `SELECT 1 And 2` is -1. Code running under VBA will evaluate 0 for the visual basic expression "1 and 2", but that's not of interest here.

Comment: Oops... I did check it with VBA, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a good answer, really it's a limitation of TSQL.

You could create a UDF for each boolean expression you need

```
CREATE FUNCTION AndIntInt
(
    @x as int,@y as int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    if (@x<>0) and (@y<>0)
        return -1
    if not((@x<>0) and (@y<>0)) 
        return  0 
    return null
END
```

used via

```
select AndIntInt(A.x,A.y) as r from A
```

Answer (score 2):

**Boolean handling**

Access seems to use the logic that given 2 booleans

- Both have to be true to return true
- Either being false returns false (regardless of nulls)
- Otherwise return null

I'm not sure if this is how other DBMS (Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL) deal with bool+null, but this answer is based on the Access determination (MySQL and SQLite agree).  The table of outcomes is presented below.

```
X      Y      A.X AND B.Y
0      0      0
0      -1     0
0      (null) 0
-1     0      0
-1     -1     -1
-1     (null) (null)
(null) 0      0
(null) -1     (null)
(null) (null) (null)
```

**SQL Server helper 1: function for boolean from any "single value"**

In SQL Server in general, this function will fill the gap for the missing `any value as boolean` functionality.  It returns a ternary result, either 1/0/null - 1 and 0 being the SQL Server equivalent of true/false (without actually being boolean).

```
drop function dbo.BoolFromAny
GO
create function dbo.BoolFromAny(@v varchar(max)) returns bit as
begin
return (case
    when @v is null then null
    when isnumeric(@v) = 1 and @v like '[0-9]%' and (@v * 1.0 = 0) then 0
    else 1 end)
end
GO
```

*Note: taking Access as a starting point, only the numeric value 0 evaluates to FALSE*
This uses some SQL Server tricks

1. everything is convertible to varchar. Therefore only one function taking varchar input is required.
2. isnumeric is not comprehensive, '.' returns 1 for `isnumeric` but will fail at `@v * 1.0`, so an explicit test for `LIKE` [0-9]%`` is required to "fix" isnumeric.
3. `@v * 1.0` is required to overcome some arithmetic issues. If you pass the string "1" into the function without *1.0, it will bomb

Now we can test the function.

```
select dbo.BoolFromAny('abc')
select dbo.BoolFromAny(1)
select dbo.BoolFromAny(0)  -- the only false
select dbo.BoolFromAny(0.1)
select dbo.BoolFromAny(-1)
select dbo.BoolFromAny('')
select dbo.BoolFromAny('.')
select dbo.BoolFromAny(null)  -- the only null
```

You can now safely use it in a query against ANY SINGLE COLUMN, such as

```
SELECT dbo.BoolFromAny(X) = 1
```

**SQL Server helper 2: function to return result of BOOL AND BOOL**

Now the next part is creating the same truth table in SQL Server.  This query shows you how two bit columns interact and the simple CASE statement to produce the same table as Access and your more complicated one.

```
select a.a, b.a,
  case
  when a.a = 0 or b.a = 0 then 0
  when a.a = b.a then 1
  end
from
(select 1 A union all select 0 union all select null) a,
(select 1 A union all select 0 union all select null) b
order by a.a, b.a
```

This is easily expressed as a function

```
create function dbo.BoolFromBits(@a bit, @b bit) returns bit as
begin
  return case
    when @a = 0 or @b = 0 then 0
    when @a = @b then 1
    end
end
```

**SQL Server conversion of other expressions (not of a single value)**

### Due to lack of support for bit-from-boolean conversion, expressions that are already [true/false/null] in SQL Server require repetition in a CASE statement.

An example is a "true boolean" in SQL Server, which cannot be the result for a column.

```
select A > B -- A=B resolves to one of true/false/null
from C
```

Needs to be expressed as

```
select case when A is null or B is null then null when A > B then 1 else 0 end
from C
```

But if A is not a scalar value but a subquery like `(select sum(x)...)`, then as you can see A will appear twice and be evaluated twice in the CASE statement (repeated).

**FINAL TEST**
Now we put all the conversion rules to use in this long expression

```
SELECT X AND Y=Z AND C FROM ..
( assume X is numeric 5, and C is varchar "H" )
( note C contributes either TRUE or NULL in Access )
```

This translates to SQL Server (chaining the two functions and using CASE)

```
SELECT dbo.BoolFromBits(
       dbo.BoolFromBits(dbo.BoolFromAny(X), CASE WHEN Y=Z then 1 else 0 end),
                       dbo.BoolFromAny(C))
FROM ...
```

**Access `Bool or bool`**

For completeness, here is the truth table for Access `bool OR bool`.  Essentially, it is the opposite of AND, so

- Both have to be false to return false
- Either being true returns true (regardless of nulls)
- Otherwise return null

The SQL SERVER case statement would therefore be

```
  case
  when a.a = 1 or b.a = 1 then 1
  when a.a = b.a then 0
  end
```

*(the omission of an ELSE clause is intentional as the result is NULL when omitted)*

Comment: This does not correctly handle a number of situations: (X=-1,Y=-1), (X != 0, Y > 1), (X != 0, Y < 1), (X > 1, Y != 0), (X < 1, Y != 0)

Comment: @cyberkiwi - The OP suggests that the values might be integers which means they could be integers > 1 and < -1. His Case expression will convert those to Null, 0 or -1 whereas in some circumstances your solution will return a value other than that. For example, (X=1, Y=2) will produce 2 in your solution but -1 in the OP case expression and thus the result is not the same. In addition, the case of (X=-1,Y=-1) is likely to occur if Access outputs X and Y as both True.

Comment: @cyberwiki In Access, when you do an expression like `5 And True` you get 5, which when treated as a boolean evaluates to `True` (because it is non-zero). So yes, true/false/unknown is the desired set, but it is _other DBMS's implementations of these_ which need to be emulated, regardless of SQL Server's implementation. Don't miss this point.

Comment: @Emtucifor, @thomas - point taken. Answer completely rewritten. Hope it makes more sense now

Comment: 1. You don't need `case..when` to implement boolean logic with `bit`. You can do `and` with `&` and `or` with `|`. 
<p>
2. You present in **SQL Server conversion of other expressions** a case statement to convert a logical predicate into a numerical or bit value. If you would look at my question again then you will see, that what I actually asked is how to improve this case statement. Also, you forgot the `unknown` case. (null<>0  is unknown, not false)

Comment: @Luther - If you look at `helper 2`, you will see the truth table being built (bit and bit).  No combination of & and | will give you the correct result, I contend that you do need the `case`. You may not need it for boolean logic, but certainly need it for SQL-bool-or-null logic

Comment: @Luther - for example your last `select A.x and exists ..` would translate to, regardless of the type of `A.x`,  a `select dbo.BoolFromBits(dbo.BoolFromAny(A.x), case when exists .. then 1 else 0 end)`. This is a technique for consistent conversion.

Comment: @cyberwiki: How does implementing bools on top of bit help me with the problem (which my question is about) that converting an arbitrary logical predicate X to bit requires me to duplicate X in a case statement? If I follow your path, how would (for example) `select x and (select count(*) from B where B.x=A.x)>2 from A` translate?

Comment: `case when (select count(*) from B where B.x=A.x)>2 then 1 else 0 end)` -- brilliant. Now suppose we had `sum(B.x)` instead of `count(*)`. How would you change the expression?

Comment: Wrong. `(select count(*) from B where B.x=A.x)` always returns an integer, `(select sum(B.x) from B where B.x=A.x)` can return NULL if no B.x matches an A.x. In this case (...)>2 is `UNKNOWN`. But `case when UNKNOWN then 1 else 0 end` yields 0 and not then NULL which I want. To get NULL, I'll have to resort to the CASE expression which I gave in my original problem statement, which unfortunately **duplicates** the predicate. `case when (select count(*) from B where B.x=A.x)>2 then 1 when not((select count(*) from B where B.x=A.x)>2) then 0 else null end)`

Comment: @Luther - You got me there. I updated the answer (part in largest font). Can't think of any way to get around repetition.

Comment: "Either being false returns false (regardless of nulls)" -- actually, it returns `0` (`SMALLINT`) e.g. `SELECT TYPENAME(CBOOL(FALSE) AND NULL);` returns `integer`, whereas `SELECT TYPENAME(CBOOL(FALSE));` returns `Boolean`.

Comment: Your "otherwise" case is not universally correct for Access because `TRUE AND NULL` sometimes evaluates to FALSE. Proof: a `CHECK` bites only when its expression evaluates to FALSE (put another way, `NULL` does not cause a `CHECK` to bite), consider `CREATE TABLE T1 (col YESNO, CHECK (col AND TRUE));` `INSERT INTO T1 (col) VALUES (NULL);` causes the `CHECK` to bite, therefore `NULL AND TRUE` evaluated to FALSE.

Comment: Similar Access wierdness: `SELECT NULL IN (TRUE);` returns `NULL`, however `SELECT TRUE IN (NULL);` returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score -1):

*EDIT: Based on additional information added to the Question and comments made on one of the suggested Answers, I am reformulating this answer:*

If you are porting to SQL Server then I would expect that you are also transforming the data to match SQL Server types. If you have a boolean field then True, False, and Unknown map to 1, 0, and NULL as a NULLable BIT field.

With this in mind, you only need to worry about transforming pure boolean values.  Expressions such as:

```
exists (select * from B where B.y=A.y)
```

and:

```
A.x in (1,2,3)
```

are already in a workable form.  Meaning, statements like:

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table))
```

and:

```
IF (value IN (list))
```

are already correct.  So you just need to worry about the fact that "1" for "True" is not by itself enough. Hence, you can convert "1" values to boolean expressions by testing if they are in fact equal to "1".  For example:

```
IF (value = 1)
```

is the equivalent of what you previously had as:

```
IF (value)
```

Putting all of this together, you should be able to simply translate all instances of pure boolean values of the old code into boolean expressions in the form of "value = 1" since a 1 will produce a True, 0 will produce False, and NULL will give you False.

HOWEVER, the real complexity is that SELECTing the value vs. testing with it via a WHERE condition is different.  Boolean expressions evaluate correctly in WHERE conditions but have no direct representation to SELECT (especially since NULL / Unknown isn't really boolean).  So, you can use the "Value = 1" translation in WHERE conditions but you will still need a CASE statement if you want to SELECT it as a result.

As mentioned briefly a moment ago, since NULL / Unknown isn't truly boolean, it is meaningless trying to convert "NULL AND NULL" to NULL for the purposes of a WHERE condition.  In effect, NULL is truly FALSE since it cannot be determined to be TRUE.  Again, this might be different for your purposes in a SELECT statement which is again why the CASE statement is your only choice there.